# sqlsrv_fetch_array returns true in php

Tags: php, sql-server

So, I've had this problem before and never solved it but now I got it again and I really want it to be solved.

In a PHP file I execute the following lines:

The problem is in the querySelect() which you can see down below..

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($dbconn, "SELECT * FROM USERS");
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC );
Logger::logg("ROW (not in method): " . var_export($row, true), LV);

querySelect("SELECT * FROM USERS",$dbconn);
```

And I get the following:
(The first output is correct and selects the first user and as you can see returns an associcative array). Then in querySelect $row is true each time. (there is more outputs of this because it does it for each user ofcourse...)

```
07/25/12 12:11:26 - ROW (not in method): array (
  'LopNr' => 1,
  'Mail' => 'xxxx                                                                                            ',
  'Password' => 'xxx',
  'Auth' => '1',
  'DisplayName' => 'xxx            ',
  'sdsd' => xx,
  'sdsd' => 'xxx',
  'ts' => 1342093599,
  'Cell' => NULL,
  'WantsSMS' => xxx,
).
07/25/12 12:11:27 - Query: SELECT * FROM USERS.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
07/25/12 12:11:27 - ROW: true.
```

querySelect is implemented like this:

```
function querySelect($query, $dbconn, $fetchLimit = 1000000)
{
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($dbconn, $query);
    Logger::logg(LOGG_QRY_ERR_VERBOSE . $query, LV);
    if ( !$stmt )
    {
        Logger::logg(LOGG_QRY_ERR);
        throw new Exception(ERR_QUERY);
    }
    $resultArray = array();
    while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) && $fetchLimit > 0)
    {
        Logger::logg("ROW: " . var_export($row, true), LV);
        $resultArray[] = $row;
        $fetchLimit--;
    }
    return $resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) && $fetchLimit > 0
```

is being interpreted as

```
$row = (sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) && $fetchLimit > 0)
```

i.e. it's including the `&& $fetchLimit > 0` in the assignment. See [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) on operator precedence.

Try changing it to

```
( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) && $fetchLimit > 0
```

or

```
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) and $fetchLimit > 0
```

(`and` has a lower precedence than `=`)

Comment: Oh, now that you're pointing it out, it's so obvious, thank you!